# Lineprinters Emulator/Virtual

Tags: printing, emulation

Is there any such thing as a virtual Lineprinter.I mean a software emulation of a printer, that outputs to screen.

I have a project to change the output of print job. My past experience with a lineprinter was tedious rounds of

```
loop:
   print
   walk down two flights
   check the output
   walk back up two flights
   edit code
got loop:
```

Anyone who thinks a lineprinter can be installed in a programmers office has not used a LinePrinter!

Googles just turning up printer emulation, as in printers that emulate other printers or virtual printer ports!

Answer (score 0):

In DOS, there is a device called "CON:" which stands for Console.

It outputs to (or from!) the console just like LPT1: outputs to the first line-printer.

Try substituting CON: instead of LPT1: when you specify your printer.

Comment: Thats not really LinePrinter output, they have different fonts, sizes etc. The Console only supports a single font.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are looking for.  If you are simply trying to capture the data and display it, you could simply install a printer on Windows and use somehething like [Redmon](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/redmon/index.htm) and Redfile (included in Redmon) to direct the output to a file which could simply be displayed using any application (assuming it is simply text).  If the output has PCL control codes you could view using an application like [PCLWorks](http://www.pclworks.com/).

Does that help? If you like the idea but Redmon doesn't work for you, I have a similar port monitor that has built in output to file, simply add a comment to this response and I'll find a way to get it to you.

Another good tool for handling lineprinter or other host type output is [RPM](http://www.brooksnet.com/).